# How do I use a div to show another specific div/text content when the div is clicked? Essentially turning a div into a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not a super experienced coder by any means, but I've been playing around a lot with neocities. I have a page going that I like how it looks so far, but I can't get it to actually function. I'm basically trying to get the category divs on the left to show the corresponding text to the right. Here's a visual if that helps.

[image: 1]

I've been googling a lot, looking through SO answers, tutorials, etc and trying to apply what I've found but I think I'm just not sure how to plug what where. (also I don't want to visually turn the "buttons" on the left into the "buttons" that seem to be the default when using the "button" element).

```css
.bio {
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic';
  display: flex;
}

.bio-cat-holder {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bio-cat {
  background: #9c2f2f;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  border: 2px solid #bbbbbb;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'VT323';
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.bio-text-box {
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid #bbbbbb;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bio">
  <div class="bio-cat-holder">
    <div class="bio-cat">GENERAL INFORMATION</div>
    <div class="bio-cat">SKILLS & ABILITIES</div>
    <div class="bio-cat">CATEGORY 3</div>
    <div class="bio-cat">CATEGORY 4</div>
    <div class="bio-cat">CATEGORY 5</div>
    <div class="bio-cat">CATEGORY 6</div>
    <div class="bio-cat">CATEGORY 7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bio-text-box">
    <div class="general">Blah Blah Blah Biography</div>
    <div id="skills">Blah blah blah skills</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed what you're doing and here's the code I ended up with. And I think this is somehow doing what you want, based on my understanding. So here's what I did in summary:

- I added IDs to each button(divs)
- Added .bio-text class to each category text
- Added a JS function that adds a click event listener to each "bio-cat" element. By default, the category text's display is set to none. When clicked, it will hide the current and shows the category text from the chosen button(div).
- Added CSS hover effect and change the cursor to pointer when it is clickable

```js
const catDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.bio-cat');
const textDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.bio-text');

for (let i = 0; i < catDivs.length; i++) {
  catDivs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    const visibleText = document.querySelector('.bio-text[style="display: block;"]');
    if (visibleText) {
      visibleText.style.display = 'none';
    }
    textDivs[i].style.display = 'block';
  });
}
```

```css
.bio-text {
  display: none;
}

.bio-cat {
  background: #9c2f2f;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  border: 2px solid #bbbbbb;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'VT323';
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bio-cat:hover {
  background: #bbbbbb;
  color: #9c2f2f;
}

.bio-text-box {
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid #bbbbbb;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bio-cat-holder">
  <div class="bio-cat" id="general-info-btn">GENERAL INFORMATION</div>
  <div class="bio-cat" id="skills-btn">SKILLS & ABILITIES</div>
  <div class="bio-cat" id="cat3-btn">CATEGORY 3</div>
  <div class="bio-cat" id="cat4-btn">CATEGORY 4</div>
  <div class="bio-cat" id="cat5-btn">CATEGORY 5</div>
  <div class="bio-cat" id="cat6-btn">CATEGORY 6</div>
  <div class="bio-cat" id="cat7-btn">CATEGORY 7</div>
</div>

<div class="bio-text-box">
  <div class="bio-text" id="general-info">
    Blah Blah Blah Biography
  </div>
  <div class="bio-text" id="skills">
    Blah blah blah skills
  </div>
  <div class="bio-text" id="cat3">
    Category 3 text
  </div>
  <div class="bio-text" id="cat4">
    Category 4 text
  </div>
  <div class="bio-text" id="cat5">
    Category 5 text
  </div>
  <div class="bio-text" id="cat6">
    Category 6 text
  </div>
  <div class="bio-text" id="cat7">
    Category 7 text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! So I tried this, and it seems the closest so far to want I want as far as keeping the site in the same layout. However clicking the categories doesn't seem to do anything when I put the code now in my site, though it works here on the snippet. (Sorry I'm not sure how to show what I've got but I copy-pasted. Here's the [site](https://nightaviation.neocities.org/characters/gemini/gemini) (there's a splash screen at first but it times out). Thanks.

Comment: Ignore my comment. The splash screen is the issue, which I think I can fix on my own. Thank you!

Comment: Hi. Just got back. Glad that helped.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need [javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) adding click [event listner](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp).

```
<button id="myButton">Click me</button>
<div id="myDiv">Original content</div>

<script>
    const button = document.getElementById("myButton");
    const div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      div.textContent = "New content";
    });
</script>
```

For your case it can be done like this,

```
<div id="cat1" class="bio-cat">GENERAL INFORMATION</div>
<div id="cat2" class="bio-cat">SKILLS & ABILITIES</div>
<div id="cat3" class="bio-cat">CATEGORY 3</div>
<div id="general" class="general">
    Blah Blah Blah Biography
</div>

<script>
    const div1 = document.getElementById("cat1");
    const div2 = document.getElementById("cat2");
    const div3 = document.getElementById("cat3");
    const div = document.getElementById("general");
    
    div1.addEventListener("click", () => {
      div.textContent = "Div 1 was clicked";
    });
    
    div2.addEventListener("click", () => {
      div.textContent = "Div 2 was clicked";
    });
    
    div3.addEventListener("click", () => {
      div.textContent = "Div 3 was clicked";
    });
</script>
```

Check **how I used ID's** with javascript. If you need to reduce the code you can use [jquery](https://jquery.com/) library or foreach loop.